# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: - popup window on activity start

Tags: android

I have been hunting for the answer to this but most seem to point to getApplicationContext() issues but I am not using getApplicationContext().
Basically I am trying to have a popup window open on start up of a activity but when the activity starts it force closes with the above error.

The code im have writen is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.installguides_menu);
    setTitleFromActivityLabel(R.id.title_text);

    btn_Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Back);
    btn_Back.setOnClickListener (btn_Back_onClick);

    btn_Ubuntu10Guide   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Ubuntu10Guide);
    btn_Ubuntu12Guide   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Ubuntu12Guide);
    btn_BacktrackGuide  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_BacktrackGuide);
    btn_DebianGuide     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_DebianGuide);

    btn_Ubuntu10Guide   .setOnClickListener (btn_Ubuntu10Guide_onClick);
    btn_Ubuntu12Guide   .setOnClickListener (btn_Ubuntu12Guide_onClick);
    btn_BacktrackGuide  .setOnClickListener (btn_BacktrackGuide_onClick);
    btn_DebianGuide     .setOnClickListener (btn_DebianGuide_onClick);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.donation_popup, null);  
             final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
               popupView, 
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

     Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
     btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

     public void onClick(View v) {
      popupWindow.dismiss();
     }});

     popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btn_Ubuntu10Guide, 50, -30);
}
```

Hope you guys can help, been hunting for the answer for hours so your my last hope!

Comment: Posting logcat would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you are not allowed to show a pop-up inside `onCreate`. It is for initializing your application and constructing your layout, but you are forcing it to display a pop-up instead.

`onStart()` is a more suitable place to show it. Override this function and show your pop-up there. If you prefer to do it in onResume(), note that the user will see it not only when they launch the application but also when they come back to it after navigating away to another activity.

**EDIT 2:** Try this for creating the pop-up in onStart or onCreate:

```
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
               this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
               inflater.inflate(findViewById(R.id.popup_layout), null, false), 
               100, 
               100, 
               true);

// delaying popup until after all application initialization is done
    findViewById(R.id.main_page_layout).post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main_page_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
       }
    });
```

Add id's to your activity and pop-up layouts using

```
android:id="@+id/main_page_layout"
```

and

```
android:id="@+id/popup_layout"
```

respectively so that they match the id's you will use in the code above.

Comment: Just tried this but still get the same error so im guessing it has something more to do with the popup code itself`

Comment: Ok im now getting a java.lang.NullPointerException error my code: http://pastebin.com/ACxiEC5z and my xml layout for the popup http://pastebin.com/cT5v5wsX

Comment: still getting a  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Why do you have only one XML file and no id's for any of the layouts? Please post your logcat output so that I can see where the error is. You should use above code in onStart not in onCreate!

Comment: There is more code to the activity and there are other layouts you just wanted the popup layout, I tried it in both onStart and onCreate.